# How to have communication between Docker Containers and A Linux VM on my windows Host

Tags: docker, networking, hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V machine and Docker running a few containers. I need them to be able to ping each other. Is there a way I can do this. Ive tried putting them on the same nat but im not sure I even accomplished that. There both on my windows host and i spin up the docker containers using a yml file.

Comment: You might need to describe the topology more, so you can get better help, i.e. are these containers in a VM, host, how are the vswitches made, etc...